# Get array of value from list of object

Tags: reactjs

i'm sure this is just a simple problem, but i just cannot solve it no matter what i do.
Suppose i have an API like this.

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "eum et est occaecati",
    "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"
  }
]
```

I want to extract the value of id and store it inside data, so the i get list like this

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
```

This is what i had tried

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(res => res.data.map(e => setData([...data, e.id])))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {data.map(e => <li key={e}>{e}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

I thought it would work, but instead of getting list of id like i wanted, i only get the id of the last object on the list.
Could someone please give me the working code, so i can learn from it?? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Why do you need ids to be on the top?

Comment: Is this because of key on li?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you. Using the `map` same as you but with tweaks. You were doing it in the wrong way.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(res => setData(res.data.map(e => e.id)))
    }, [])
```

**Explanation:**

`res.data.map(e => e.id))` => return an array of ids

`setData(res.data.map(e => e.id))` => hook which sets the data

Comment: Yep, thank you so much. I guess it's all because my lack of understanding in js haha

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map`.

```
const arr = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "eum et est occaecati",
    "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"
  }
];

const newArr = arr.map(ele => ele.id);

console.log(newArr);
```

**Update**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(res => setData(res.data.map(ele => ele.id)))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {data.map(ele => <li key={ele}>{ele}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Comment: yeah, but it doesn't work on my case. I'am trying to store the value into a state using Hooks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "eum et est occaecati",
    "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"
  }
]

arr.map(i => i.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const ids = data.map(e => e.id)
```

This will map the `id` field of each element from `data` into `ids`.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not understand the reason of such transformation. But this code should help you.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(res => setData(res.data.map(e => e.id)))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {data.map(e => <li key={e}>{e}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Comment: just trying some stuff haha